# MySQL ERROR 1064： 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8'

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I create a database specified its charset as `utf8` by:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS gtfs;
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

but encounter the following error：

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 1

The version of MySQL:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Uhm... too ambitious with the `;` there...!?

Comment: set charset UTF8 and set locale for UTF8_GENERAL_CI

Comment: Just to add some clarification, your attempt was almost right. The sentence you have to use is the one you have proposed, but in SQL when you use the `;` it is understand as a sentence that ends, so the database is not being created as you want.

Removing the `;` that split your sentences will make you get the instruction you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS gtfs
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```